# Derivatives. Getting things into and out of d()

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

In a textbook I encountered this:
$$\frac{H}{\omega_s}2\omega_r\frac{d\omega_r}{dt} = (P_m-P_e)\frac{d\delta}{dt}$$
The left-hand side of this equation can be rewritten to give
$$\frac{H}{\omega_s}\frac{d\left(\omega^2_r\right)}{dt} = (P_m-P_e)\frac{d\delta}{dt}$$

But to me it seems that $\frac{d(w_r^2)}{dt}$ is the same as  $\frac{d}{dt}w_r^2$ which is just $2w_r$ and not $2w_r\frac{dw_r}{dt}$
What am I missing here?

EDIT: Got it! If it were $\frac{d(t^2)}{dt}$ then it would be $2t$ But $w_r$ is a function of $t$ so you need to use the chain rule!

Comment: Short answer: the chain rule

Comment: $\omega_r$ is a function of $t$. So use chain rule

Comment: I have updated you post to use inline text and MathJax to replace your image (edit may be pending).  Can you please check that it is correct?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine.